# Cross Compiling For Bigendian - No valid architectures?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, endianness

### tl;dr

I can't compile glibc on powerpc/mips/armeb/sparc. How can I test bigendian without emulating a whole system?

### Problem Description

I am currently trying to test some code to ensure that it works on a big-endian system (it doesn't) and fix any big-endian errors. Currently I am using `qemu-system-ppc` with a PowerPC debian image and compiling within that image, as well as running gdb there, etc. However, this is extremely inefficient and I know there is a better way.

As such I followed [this](http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/) tutorial to create a cross compiler so I could compile my source to a big-endian system, then run the user-space `qemu-???` to test it without the overhead of running the entire OS in emulated space (in particular with the `-S` switch I could run gdb on host which is **much** faster).

### Attempt #1:

First try was powerpc. At first I just ran the configure with `--target=powerpc` but realized that I should use a full triplet and went with `powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu`. Unfortunately, when I get to the glibc portion I run into the problem that my gcc does not support IBM 128-bit long doubles (it only supports IEEE). I googled around and there doesn't seem to be a fix (aside from updating gcc past v4.1 - I'm at 6.2 right now).

### Attempt #2:

Let's try mips then, I have more experience with it anyways (from university). This makes it to the glibc portion again, but this time it complains that it can't determine the ABI. I tried it with all of `-linux-gnu` `-gneabi` `-eabi` and `-none` but it couldn't determine the ABI for any of them.

### Attempt #3:

Alright, time to try armeb. This time it gets past determining the ABI, then dumps a message saying that the target is not yet supported by glibc. Same story with sparc.

### Question

Given that all of the above failed - how can I compile a cross-compiler from my little-endian system to a big-endian system which will generate executables I can run in user-space with qemu?

Comment: It is really nothing to do with endianess. Your cross-compiler toolchain is just not built/installed correctly. I suggest you to either download a precompiled toolchain or use a dedicated tool like crosstool-ng.

Comment: Wow, neat. I have never seen crosstool before. Indeed for all of the configurations I tested above it says: `C Library : none (threads: none)` I do need the c library, so I switched to one of the versions where it has a c library. I still wish I could compile myself though.

Comment: If I remember correctly, most PowerPC cores have the possibility to set endianess through the MMU setup. Using a CPU that can execute either endianess would be ideal for your tests. Not sure if that's possible without writing the ABI yourself. I once wrote a simple ABI for a PowerPC E200 core and I'm pretty sure that one option was to set endianess.

Comment: Yep, just checked the manual. You can set it in the MAS1 register. Whether or not that is supported by your specific PowerPC is another story.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just tried building a cross-compilation toolchain with ct-ng and found that since my gcc is version 6.2 I can't compile any of the version 5.2 compilers it ships with all of its samples. Is there an easy way to tell it to use clang to compile (even just letting it use an old version of gcc would work, I could revert my gcc package until its old enough).